# Prove that $\exists$ U: $P$ is self adjoint if and only if $P=P_U$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $P \in L(V)$ is such that $P^2 = P$. Prove that there is a subspace U of V such that $P= P_U$ if and only if P is self adjoint.

First suppose that $P = P_U$ Show this implies that P is self adjoint.

Now suppose that P is self adjoint. Show this implies $P = P_U$.

I have no idea how to do this question beyond the structure of the proof like that, any advice?

Comment: What is $V$?  What does $P_U$ mean?

Comment: Presumably the orthogonal projection?

Comment: V is a finite dimensional vector space and P is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace U. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hint: Consider the column space of $P$.

Comment: @Soaps: Thank you.  It is also an inner product space, right?  Over the real or complex numbers?

Comment: I believe it is assumed to be over the real and complex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $P_U$ is self adjoint, it's enough to take any matrix representation of $P_U$.  For example: if $U$ is a space with basis $u_1,\dots,u_n$, then 
$$
P_U = u_1u_1^* + \cdots + u_nu_n^*
$$
If $P$ is self-adjoint with $P^2 = P$, we can note that all eigenvalues must be $1$ or $0$ and apply the spectral decomposition to find $P = VDV^*$ where $V$ is unitary and
$$
D = \pmatrix{1&&&&&\\&\ddots&&&&\\&&1&&&\\&&&0&&\\&&&&\ddots&\\&&&&&0}
$$
It follows that $P = P_U$, where $U$ is the span of the columns of $V$ corresponding to the $1$s in $D$.